# Axios not resolving, state is still a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch, state

I've been using axios for some time but I just cant get around this.
Tried both axios and fetch but it just doesn't resolve my promise and my state remains a promise.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const login = async (state, payload) => {

    try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/token-auth/', payload)
        const data = await response.data



         return  {
            user: data.user,
            loggedIn: true,
            error: false
        }
    }


     catch (error) {
        return {
            user: null,
            loggedIn: false,
            error: true
        }

    }


}      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/token-auth/', payload)
        return  await response.data

    }


     catch (error) {
        return {
            user: null,
            loggedIn: false,
            error: true
        }

    }


}
```

It always returns a promise and not the data, but if I `console.log`, I get the data on the console.

Comment: It looks like you've posted part of the code twice.

Comment: You will always get a Promise after calling an async function. Either perform the operation after await statement or use `.then` when calling the async function.

Comment: Show the rest of your code that relates to "your state remaining a promise." What you're showing right now is your how you make your API call, so this doesn't really show us the whole picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` function will always return promise.

The word “async” before a function means one simple thing: a function always returns a promise. Other values are wrapped in a resolved promise automatically.

So you have to handle the promise when you call an async function.

Try this.

```
import axios from "axios";

export const login = async (state, payload) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:8080/token-auth/",
      payload
    );
    const data = await response.data;
    return {
      user: data.user,
      loggedIn: true,
      error: false
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      user: null,
      loggedIn: false,
      error: true
    };
  }
};

(async function() {
  let response = await login(...);
  console.log(response);
})()
```

Example:

```js
async function f() {
  return 1;
}


//Handle promise with then
f().then(console.log); // 1
```